# Google Drive and Google Photos

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

When you create the folder "Google Photos" in Drive. Is that just a pointer or is it an actual folder with all the pictures from Photos taking up storage in drive?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a pointer, that is an actual folder with all the pictures and videos from Photos taking up storage in drive if you upload in original quality.

From [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0):

> Your photos and videos are stored using your [Google Account's storage space](https://drive.google.com/settings/storage?pli=1).
>
> - If you upload photos directly to Google Drive, they will count against your storage quota.
> - If you upload using Google Photos or Backup and sync, it will count against your storage quota if you upload in original quality.

From the [Help Center](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0) also see **What happens when you change or delete a photo**.

Comment: How sure are we that it will remain in "original quality"?

Comment: And if you dont upload them in original quality? Then how does the drive folder work?

Comment: @MikeHouska: It works in the same, but if you don't upload in original quality it will save some space for you. https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791